# "What about you" in the following context is correct?

Tags: word-choice

My friend sent me message like this:

> **He**: "Hi, how are you"
>
> **Me**: "I'm fine, thank you. **What about you?**"
>
> **He**: I see television
>
> **Me**: Are you watching television? nice, I hope that you **enjoy of that**.
>
> **Me**: Actually I don't understand a lot **in** football...

By the way I would like to get your feedback on the rest of this conversation as I mentioned above, because I have some doubts about some things that I marked as you can see in the text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What about you?" is fine.

Him saying "I see television" is plain wrong, it's "I'm **watching** television".

"I hope that you enjoy of that." is wrong, that "of" doesn't belong here. Also, the "that" after the "hope" can be optionally dropped.

That "in" in "Actually I don't understand a lot in football." should be "about". There seems to be a short pause between "actually" and "I", so a comma should go between them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Just to be clear with one of your things, Do you mean that I should say "I hope you enjoy that"?

Comment: And in addition I meant to ask which time is used when we are talking about "enjoy". Should it be "I hope that you are enjoying"?